# Ultimate Special Offers. How to set a place for the table?

Tags: position, shopify

I have a question about Ultimate Special Offers plugin. Has anybody used it?

The problem is that this plugin sets the table with discounts in a special place where it wants. In my case, it shows up under the "add to cart" button. But I want it to appear above the button. How can I regulate the place where the table shows up?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. One is to dig into your theme and move the table yourself. If you right-click the element displaying the table while having your browser console open, you will spot where it is in the HTML that makes up your page. Now click the Add to cart button, and see where it is. Memorize the name of the button, and now look for that in your product.liquid page. Chances are, the plugin itself has some liquid, so you can cut it out of the page, and move it the before the add to cart button in the liquid.

If all that seems like a mountain to climb, just ask the makers of the plugin to do it for you. It is a simple task for them, and should take them a minute to do. If they choose to ignore you, I would call them out as unreliable, and try a different plugin, from a company that will help you with your simple task.

Comment: thanks so much. I did like you suggested and I dug into the code of the product page and found that plugin places the table into div with class saso-volumes. So I created div.saso-volumes in the place where I want to see the table on the page and that's it. Now the table is in the right place!